# Magento 2 | Create frontend route

Tags: magento2, router

I want to create a custom frontend route. It should have this link:

> www.mysite.com/myroute

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="myroute" frontName="myroute">
            <module  />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I've already created the **route** but I don't know where to place the **controller**.
Can you help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: You can accept answer. If it will helpful for you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is complete example of how the fronted route work it is combination of   **controller**,**layout**,**block** and **template**.

**Route**

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Simple Hello World Module
 *
 * @category QaisarSatti
 * @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
 * @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
 * @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
 *
 */-->   
<config 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
    <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
      <module name="QaisarSatti_HelloWorld" />
    </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

**Controller**

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Simple Hello World Module
 *
 * @category QaisarSatti
 * @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
 * @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
 * @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
 *
 */

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Layout File**

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Simple Hello World Module
 *
 * @category QaisarSatti
 * @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
 * @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
 * @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
 *
 */-->
<page 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      layout="1column" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block 
            class="QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" 
            name="HelloWorld" 
            template="QaisarSatti_HelloWorld::HelloWorld.phtml">
        .
      </block>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

Template File

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/HelloWorld.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Catalog Product Rewrite Helper
 *
 * @category QaisarSatti
 * @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
 * @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
 * @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
 *
 */
echo 'Hello World';
```

**Custom Block**

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Simple Hello World Module
 *
 * @category QaisarSatti
 * @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
 * @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
 * @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
 *
 */

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('First Hello World Module'));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-helloworld-module/)

Comment: How to enable and disable frontend routing?

Answer (score 4):

create **Index.php** controller in on below path :

> /app/code/UO/NewsletterUV/Controller/Index/

```
<?php
namespace UO\NewsletterUV\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Controller call successfully";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for not overcomplicating things, and showing that you can produce output directly without needing to define layout, template and block.

Comment: How to enable and disable frontend routing?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Create PHP file at `app/code/UO/NewsletterUV/Controller/Index/` with `Index.php`.

Code should be like this in that file.

```
namespace UO\NewsletterUV\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

/**
 * Class Index
 * @package UO\NewsletterUV\Controller\Index\Index
 */
class Index extends Action
{


    /**
     * Function execute
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {  
        echo "Rout Called";

    }
}
```

Comment: How to enable and disable frontend routing?

Answer (score 3):

For this route, the controller must be in `UO/NewsletterUv/Controllers ...`

So if you access `www.mysite.com/myroute` -> it will call `UO/Newsletter/Controllers/Index/Index.php`

If you access `www.mysite.com/myroute/my-action` -> it will call `UO/Newsletter/Controllers/MyAction/Index.php`.

And so on...

The Controllers content looks like Rohan's answer.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is helpful info.  But I'm pretty sure it is Controller, not Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link http://infoeverysolution.com/index.php/2019/05/23/magento-routes-define/ to define the routes in magento 2